# Mock Method in Swift

Tags: swift

I have the following ClassA and ClassB in swift:

```
protocol ClassBProtocol {
  func doSomething(
    completionHandler: @escaping (
      ClassBProtocol?,
      Error?
    ) -> Void
  )
}

class ClassB: ClassBProtocol
{
  init(key: String) {
      self.key = key
  }

  func doSomething(
    completionHandler: @escaping (
      ClassBProtocol?,
      Error?
    ) -> Void
  ) {
    // Does some network requests and if it was successful does the following:
    completionHandler(ClassB(), nil)
  }
}
```

```
public class ClassA: ClassAProtocol {

  static var instance: ClassA? = nil
  static let initQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "queue")
  static let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 1)

  @objc public static func getSomething(
    withKey key: String,
    completionHandler: @escaping (ClassA?, Error?) -> Void
  ) {
    ClassA.initQueue.async {
      ClassA.semaphore.wait()
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if let objectA = ClassA.instance {
          ClassA.semaphore.signal()
          completionHandler(objectA, nil)
          return
        }

        let objectB = ClassB(withKey: key)

        objectB.doSomething { response, error in
          guard let response = response else {
            ClassA.semaphore.signal()
            completionHandler(nil, error)
            return
          }
          let objectA = ClassA()
          ClassA.instance = objectA
          ClassA.semaphore.signal()

          completionHandler(objectA, nil)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And the following test case to test ClassA.getSomething() and ensure a race condition does not happen:

```
  func testgetSomethingReturnsSameInstance() {
    let expectation1 = self.expectation(description: "getSomething 1 completed")
    let expectation2 = self.expectation(description: "getSomething 2 completed")
    let expectation3 = self.expectation(description: "getSomething 3 completed")

    var client1: ClassA?
    var client2: ClassA?
    var client3: ClassA?


    ClassA.getSomething() { (client, error) in
      client1 = client
      expectation1.fulfill()
    }

    ClassA.getSomething() { (client, error) in
      client2 = client
      expectation2.fulfill()
    }

    ClassA.getSomething() { (client, error) in
      client3 = client
      expectation3.fulfill()
    }

    waitForExpectations(timeout: 10) { (error) in
      XCTAssertEqual(client1, client2)
      XCTAssertEqual(client2, client3)
      XCTAssertEqual(client1, client3)
    }
  }
```

The doSomething in ClassB sends a network request and will return an object. I need to mock this method to do the following:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
  completionHandler(response: ClassB(), error: nil)
}
```

But couldn't find any way to do it. Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: Hmm... is there any particular reason that you're using NSObject here?

Comment: What is `ClassB`? You're using it in the question but it seems to just appear out of nowhere.

Comment: Go for Swift Concurrency and get rid of the objective-c-ish stuff.

Comment: What is `ClassAProtocol`? That's probably the thing we would need to use to provide a "Mock" ClassA. If that's what you're trying to do? Also, it looks like everything in `ClassA` is static. Is that for any particular reason?

Comment: I've removed the reference to NSObject. I'm using it but it's not related to this issue.

Comment: What @vadian said 

Comment: @Mat the reason I asked is because it's VERY unusual to use (or need to use) NSObject in any Swift projects any more.

Comment: @Fogmeister yes the method has to be static in this case. I understand it's not the best practice but in this case it has to be this way.

Comment: Your use of `@objc` implies that you need to call `ClassA.getSomething` from Objective-C. Is that accurate?  If so, your use of `NSObject` was correct and you should put it back. The `completionHandler` argument type (in `ClassA.getSomething`) isn't valid unless `ClassA` inherits `NSObject`.

Answer (score 1):

It'd be easier to understand your code if you used reasonable names. I suspect `ClassB` wraps an API, and `ClassA` holds some value (like a database) that you want to fetch from the API exactly once. So let's rename `ClassBProtocol` and `ClassB` accordingly:

```
protocol API {
  func fetch(completion: @escaping (Result<Data, Error>) -> Void)
}

class LiveAPI: API {
  let key: String

  init(key: String) {
    self.key = key
  }

  func fetch(completion: @escaping (Result<Data, Error>) -> Void) {
    // Do some network requests to get the real `Data` or a real error, and then:
    completion(.success(Data()))

    // or in case of error:
    // completion(.failure(error))
  }
}
```

Then let's rename `ClassA` to `Database` and put `getSomething` on hold, leaving just this:

```
public class Database: NSObject {
  private init(data: Data) {
    // construct myself from the raw data
  }
}
```

Now, how to fetch the database exactly once, the first time it's requested?

The general advice from Apple engineers is to avoid potentially blocking operations in blocks you send to Dispatch queues. In this case, `semaphore.wait()` is a potentially blocking operation.

Furthermore, synchronous code is easier to test than asynchronous code, but you've made everything asynchronous. The first thing your `getSomething` does is an async dispatch, and a significant chunk of state (the set of pending completion handlers) is hidden away in Dispatch data structures that we cannot access.

Instead of using `semaphore` and `initQueue`, let's manually and synchronously track the completion handlers that need to be called when the database has been fetched. There are three states:

- We haven't started fetching the database.
- We've started fetching the database, but it's still downloading and we have one or more completion handlers to be called when it's finished.
- We've finished fetching the database and there are no completion handlers to call.

We'll store these three mutually-exclusive states using an `enum`, and guard access to the stored state using a `DispatchQueue`:

```
extension Database {
  // All access to q_fetchState must be on q!
  private static var q_fetchState: FetchState = .unstarted
  private static let q = DispatchQueue(label: "initQueue")

  private typealias Completion = (Result<Database, Error>) -> Void

  private enum FetchState {
    case unstarted
    case started([Completion])
    case done(Result<Database, Error>)
  }
}
```

When asked for the database, we examine the state and act appropriately:

```
extension Database {
  @objc
  public static func getDatabase(
    apiKey key: String,
    completion objc_completion: @escaping (Database?, Error?) -> Void
  ) {
    let completion: Completion = {
      switch $0 {
      case .failure(let error): objc_completion(nil, error)
      case .success(let database): objc_completion(database, nil)
      }
    }

    q.sync {
      switch q_fetchState {
      case .unstarted:
        q_fetchState = .started([completion])
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
          let api = LiveAPI(key: key)
          api.fetch { result in
            let result = result.map { Database(data: $0) }

            let completions = q.sync {
              guard case .started(let completions) = q_fetchState else {
                preconditionFailure()
              }
              q_fetchState = .done(result)
              return completions
            }

            for completion in completions {
              completion(result)
            }
          }
        }

      case .started(let array):
        q_fetchState = .started(array + [completion])

      case .done(let result):
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
          completion(result)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Notice that there are no blocking operations performed under `q`, so it's safe and efficient to use `q.sync` instead of `q.async`, and we'll see later that it makes the function more testable.

Okay, now back to your actual question, which I interpret as: How do we mock the API? Since we already have an `API` protocol, we want to make `getDatabase` generic over a type conforming to `API`, and make it take an instance of that type:

```
extension Database {
  static func getDatabase<A: API>(
    api: A,
    completion: @escaping (Result<Database, Error>) -> Void
  ) {
    q.sync {
      switch q_fetchState {
      case .unstarted:
        q_fetchState = .started([completion])
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
          api.fetch { result in
            let result = result.map { Database(data: $0) }

            let completions = q.sync {
              guard case .started(let completions) = q_fetchState else {
                preconditionFailure()
              }
              q_fetchState = .done(result)
              return completions
            }

            for completion in completions {
              completion(result)
            }
          }
        }

      case .started(let array):
        q_fetchState = .started(array + [completion])

      case .done(let result):
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
          completion(result)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

These changes mean the method is no longer compatible with Objective-C. So let's add an overload with the old, Objective-C-compatible signature:

```
  @objc
  public static func getDatabase(
    apiKey key: String,
    completion: @escaping (Database?, Error?) -> Void
  ) {
    return getDatabase(api: LiveAPI(key: key)) {
      switch $0 {
      case .failure(let error): completion(nil, error)
      case .success(let database): completion(database, nil)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now we're ready to write a mock implementation of `API`. Based on the code you posted, it would look like this:

```
struct BadTestAPI: API {
  let result: Result<Data, Error>

  func fetch(completion: @escaping (Result<Data, Error>) -> Void) {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
      completion(result)
    }
  }
}
```

But I don't like this implementation for at least three reasons:

- It hardcodes a 0.5 second delay. Yuck. We want test cases to run as fast as possible!
- It doesn't make it easy to verify that `fetch` is only called once.
- It doesn't let us control more precisely when it calls the completion handler.

Instead, let's write the mock implementation this way:

```
class TestAPI: API {
  let ex = XCTestExpectation(description: "api.fetch called")
  var completion: ((Result<Data, Error>) -> Void)? = nil

  func fetch(completion: @escaping (Result<Data, Error>) -> Void) {
    XCTAssertNil(self.completion)
    self.completion = completion
    ex.fulfill()
  }
}
```

Now we can write the test case to use this implementation:

```
final class TestDatabase: XCTestCase {
  func testGetDatabaseReturnsSameInstance() {
    class Record {
      let ex = XCTestExpectation()
      var database: Database? = nil
    }

    let api = TestAPI()
    let records = [Record(), Record(), Record()]

    XCTAssertNil(api.completion)

    for record in records {
      Database.getDatabase(api: api) {
        XCTAssertNil(record.database)
        record.database = try! $0.get()
        record.ex.fulfill()
      }
    }

    self.wait(for: [api.ex], timeout: 10)

    for record in records {
      XCTAssertNil(record.database)
    }

    api.completion!(.success(Data()))

    wait(for: records.map(\.ex), timeout: 10)

    XCTAssertNotNil(records[0].database)
    for record in records.dropFirst() {
      XCTAssertEqual(record.database, records[0].database)
    }
  }
}
```

Here are some things this test case verifies:

- `api.fetch` is not called before `Database.getDatabase`.
- `api.fetch` is only called once.
- No completion handler is called more than once.
- The `getDatabase` completion handlers are called after the `api.fetch` completion handler.